# Parsing charAt(i) as either char or int (JS)

Tags: javascript

I have an alphanumeric string that I need to parse. Each character needs manipulation based on the character's ASCII code, and the kind of manipulation depends on whether or not it is a number or a character in that position. I currently have:

```
for(var i=0; i< len; i++) {
  var asciiVal = str.charCodeAt(i);
  if(asciiVal >=48 && asciiVal <=57) {
    //do stuff for num here
  }
  else {
    //do stuff for char here
  }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this than comparing the ascii values to the bounds for 0-9? I am a JS newbie, using this one JS file for a overall Java web project. Thank you for your help!

Comment: What exact stuff do you need to do for numbers and characters?

Comment: Well you could save the values of `.charCodeAt()` for the strings "0" and "9", so that you wouldn't have to hard-code those, but since JavaScript always works with Unicode they'll always be the same.

Comment: @VisioN I need to do some math with the values (either ascii val or actual number) and sum it.